# Javascript function does not get passed paramrter

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

(function setFont() {
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++) {
document.all[i].style.fontFamily = "Verdana";
document.all[i].style.fontSize = "16";
document.all[i].style.color="black";
}
})();

(function abc(a)
{
alert(a);
ansArray = ['a'];  
for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
{ 
document.write('<input type = "button" value = "a">');
document.write('<input type = "button" value = "b">');
}
var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
//alert(myButton.length);
myButton[0].onclick = function() {
    if(ansArray[0] == 'a')
        myButton[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    else
        myButton[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
};

myButton[1].onclick = function() {
    if(ansArray[0] == 'b')
        myButton[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    else
        myButton[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
})();
setFont();
</script>
</head>

<body onload="abc(2)">
</body>
</html>
```

A javascript function abc(a) does not get the value 2 passed from `<body onload = "abc(5)">`. It says undefined. How to pass the parameters in a javascript function. I have posted it earlier as well but the parameter was not there, on giveing the parameter i found the problem.Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: calling a function inside the round brakets cause to be called when the script tag is fully loaded, not on the onload event, you should really remove those brackets...

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a closure, it's not exposed to the public but it is executed right after it's created.
And then it's gone.

It's not there to look cool, it has its purpose. Just make normal functions to get it work

---

```
(function(a) {
  // immediately called and 'garbaged'
})(a);
```

vs.

```
function publicAlwaysCallable(a) {
  console.log(a); // call me when you like
}
```

Comment: Normal function I tried does not work in IE but works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: @user1767304 Try it with [`window.onload`](http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter4.html) and for the script tag with `<script type="text/javascript">` instead. IE has so many flaws, you should consider a library which deals across browsers, like `jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use immediate function in this case. Declare it like this:

```
function abc(a) { ... }
```

If for some reason you want to encapsulate your code into closure you can do it like this:

```
(function(export) {
    export.abc = function(a) { ... };
    ...
})(window);
```

Comment: function abc(a) { ... } - this way does not work in IE but works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: I got the answer the function to be called at the script body not on onload event. Thanks every body

Answer (score 0):

The normal function (not closure) function abc(a){ ... } with the button click handlers are to be called at the end of the script. Not on onload event of the page. Now it works in IE9 also

Thanks everybody for your valuable suggestions.